# Grafana: join variables, retrieved from sql queries

Tags: sql, variables, grafana

I have 2 variables.

1. client.
   Query:

   ```
      SELECT
        title AS __text,
        concat('"', id::text,'"') AS __value
      FROM clients
      WHERE active=true
   ```

For value I use concatenation with quotation marks as some values can take string-values.

2. order.
   Order:

   ```
     select name
       from orders 
       where concat('"',client_id::text,'"') =ANY(ARRAY[${client:csv}])
   ```

And join between 2 variables does not work - I receive the error like:

```
    Templating [order] Error updating options: pq: column “1106102844810989568” does not exist
```

Without concatenation join working well, but it is not a target case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Can you provide some sample data to understand your problem better? What does it mean `some values can be strings-values`. Originally they are IDs and by default integers.

Comment: Hi, probably, I incorrectly expressed idea. Originally they are IDs. But for some reasons, without cast to quotations, join does not work properly

Comment: What is `client_id::text` or `client:csv`? From the error message it looks like it has the value "1106102844810989568". Can you use the query inspector in Grafana and inspect the generated query?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is following: I replaced ${client:csv} on  ${client:sqlstring}

So the query for 2 variable as follows:

```
  select name
    from orders 
    where concat('"',client_id::text,'"') =ANY(ARRAY[${client:sqlstring}])
```